# Git: get a list of commits that updated a submodule

Tags: git, github

Is there a handy command (or mechanism in GitHub) to get a list of commits that updated the submodule of my repo to a new version?

Using GitHub I have the ability to click on any file in the repo and view the history... but if I click on the submodule it just takes me to the submodule's repo.

For example:

```
my-submodule@12c3dd3    some commit message (#1234)    11 hours ago
```

The question I'm ultimately trying to answer is: "Before we updated 11 hours ago, when was the last time we updated that submodule?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check what the history of that submodule is:

```
$ git log -- <path_to_submodule>

commit <module_hash1>
Author: Blah
Date:   Tue Dec 12 13:15:02 2017 -0600

    some commit message

commit <module_hash2>
Author: Blah
Date:   Tue Dec 12 13:15:02 2016 -0600

    some other commit message
```

To see the diff, you then do a git diff:

```
$ git diff <module_hash2> <module_hash1>
```

To see the commit messages in that range:

```
$ git log <module_hash2>..<module_hash1>
```

Comment: `git log -- <path_to_submodule>` was all I needed. Thanks!